# Why EF Core loads child entities, when I query it without .Include()

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, eager-loading

I have a simple One-To-Many relationship.
Parent:

```
public class Customer
    {
        public Customer(string name, string email)
        {
            Name = name;
            Email = email;
        }

        public Customer(string name, string email, long mobile)
            : this(name, email)
        {
            Mobile = mobile;
        }

        //for EF
        private Customer() { }

        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string Email { get; private set; }
        public long? Mobile { get; private set; }
        public List<Transaction> Transactions { get; private set; }

        public void AddTransactions(IEnumerable<Transaction> transactions)
        {
            if(Transactions == null)
                Transactions = new List<Transaction>();

            Transactions.AddRange(transactions);
        }
    }
```

Child:

```
public class Transaction
    {
        public Transaction(DateTimeOffset date, decimal amount, Currency currency, Status status)
        {
            TransactionDate = date;
            Amount = amount;
            CurrencyCode = currency;
            Status = status;
        }

        //for EF
        private Transaction() { }
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public DateTimeOffset TransactionDate { get; private set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; private set; }
        public Currency CurrencyCode { get; private set; }
        public Status Status { get; private set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; private set; }
    }
```

There is a simple method, which queries one Customer and calls SingleOrDefault on it. After that it queries transactions, and when they are loaded, Customer's Transactions becomes from null to Count=5(transactions which I loaded). Why? In configuration I didn't specify .UseLazyLoadingProxies().

```
var customerQuery = _dbContext.Customers.AsQueryable();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Email))
                customerQuery = customerQuery.Where(c => c.Email == request.Email);

            if (request.CustomerId.HasValue)
                customerQuery = customerQuery.Where(c => c.Id == request.CustomerId.Value);

            var customer = await customerQuery.SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
//here customer has null collection of transactions
            if (customer == null)
                throw new NotFoundException("Not Found.");

            var transactions = await _dbContext.Transactions
                .Where(t => t.CustomerId == customer.Id)
                .OrderByDescending(t => t.TransactionDate)
                .Take(5)
                .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

//here customer has 5 transactions.
            customer.AddTransactions(transactions);
//here it has 10, because of method (following the DDD, it is used for providing business invariant)
```

EF configuration:

```
 public class CustomerEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(c => c.Id)
                .HasMaxLength(10);

            builder.Property(c => c.Email)
                .HasMaxLength(25)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(c => c.Mobile)
                .HasMaxLength(10);

            builder.Property(c => c.Name)
                .HasMaxLength(30)
                .IsRequired();

            //uniqueness constraint
            builder.HasIndex(c => c.Email)
                .IsUnique();

            builder.HasMany(t => t.Transactions)
                .WithOne(t => t.Customer)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.CustomerId);
        }

////////////////////////////
public class TransactionEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Transaction>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Transaction> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(t => t.Amount)
                .HasColumnType("decimal(10, 2)");
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's normal behaviour. [Relationship fix-up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data).

Comment: @Gert Arnold, so what can I deal with it? Ensure .AsNoTracking(). I don't think it is a good solution(it fixed the problem, but if I want to SaveChanges()?). I don't want to some separate query affected my previous query.

Comment: Why do you want to deal with it? What's the problem?

Comment: use short-lived contexts, or just create a new one for the piece of code where you don't want other navigation properties to be filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behaviour and a consequence of long-lived DbContexts. Perhaps explain why this behaviour is undesirable?

Option 1: use AsNoTracking(). This tells EF not to associate loaded instances with the DbContext. Auto-wireup will not happen.

Option 2: Use shorter-lived DbContexts. Module level DbContexts can be accessed across multiple methods. Using shorter-lived DbContexts bound in `using` blocks means calls wont need to worry about sharing references.